# ミリ秒をhh:mm:ss SSSに簡単に変換する方法

Tags: java

Javaで実行時間の計測処理を書こうとしたのですが、`System.currentTimeMillis()`や`System.nanoTime()`等で取得したミリ秒に対して、`hh:mm:ss SSS`の形式で文字列を取得したいだけなのにタイムゾーン考慮の必要性まで出てきて正直戸惑っています。

Pythonまでとは言わないまでも、もう少し簡単な方法はないでしょうか？自分で実装するしかありませんか？
Guavaの`stopWatch`クラスも見てみましたが、指定形式への変換はなさそうでした。もしかしたら見落としているかもしれませんが･･･

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss SSS");
System.out.println(date.format((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000));
```

上記の場合、出力結果が

```
09:00:00 042
```

と出てしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

調べました。

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html

があるようですね。

```
private static String format(long startTime, long endTime) {

    String diffTime = DurationFormatUtils.formatPeriod(startTime,
            endTime, "HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    return diffTime;

}
```

Comment: これはいいですね！ありがとうございます。時間の表示がなかったので編集させていただきました。

Answer (score 2):

Joda-TimeではPeriodFormatterがありますが、Java8ではPeriodやDurationをフォーマットする方法は提供されていません。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827047/formatting-a-duration-in-java-8-jsr310

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。使い方はこちらが参考になりそうでした。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585883/understanding-joda-time-periodformatter
表示が柔軟ではありますが、手続きが少し煩雑ですね。

Comment: こちらも参考として追加しておきます。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440557/joda-time-period-to-string

Answer (score 0):

以下のformat()メソッドを共通処理として自分で実装し、
必要なところから呼び出すのが一番簡単ではないでしょうか？

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println(format(startTime, endTime));


}

private static String format(long startTime, long endTime) {
    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar result = Calendar.getInstance();

    start.setTimeInMillis(startTime);
    end.setTimeInMillis(endTime);

    long sa = end.getTimeInMillis() - start.getTimeInMillis() - result.getTimeZone().getRawOffset();

    result.setTimeInMillis(sa);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");

    return sdf.format(result.getTime());
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。しかし実装するのは最終手段とさせてください･･･数ある(有名ドコロの)Javaライブラリ(Joda-Time、Guava、またはJava8の時刻API等々)にはこのくらいのものはあるのではないか？という趣旨の質問ですので。